Resolving runtime NZEC Error in Python code
I was solving a problem on HackerEarth which is as follows:

You are provided an array A of size N that contains non-negative integers. Your task is to determine whether the number that is formed by selecting the last digit of all the N numbers is divisible by 10. Print "Yes" if possible and "No" if not.

Here's what I did:
size = int(input())
integers = input()
integers = [i for i in integers.split(' ')]

last_digit = [i[-1] for i in integers]

number = int(''.join(last_digit))

if number % 10 == 0:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")

The code seems correct to me, but the problem is that the online HackerEarth platform throws a runtime error NZEC, about which I have no idea. So, I want to know why(and what kind of) error occured here and what is the problem with my code.

What do the inputs look like ? NZEC means non zero exit code, not very helpful but it seems to me this refers to the exit code of one of your inputs

You could refer to this

@user26346636 were you able to figure out the issue?

@FreePalestine Yes, thank you so much!

https://help.hackerearth.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002673433-types-of-errors
Hackerearth says

For interpreted languages like Python, NZEC will usually mean


Usually means that your program has either crashed or raised an uncaught exception

Many runtime errors

Usage of an external library that is not used by the judge



For your case:
number = int(''.join(last_digit))

number is becoming a very very big number which is the reason you are getting NZEC error (they have limited memory and time to execute the problem)
little modified code:
size = int(input())
integers = input()
integers = [i for i in integers.split(' ')]

last_digit = [i[-1] for i in integers]

number = ''.join(last_digit)   # keeping the number as string

if number[-1] == '0':          # checking the last digit of the string to be 0
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")


But I have one issue, that is, how do I know that at which step of the program the time limit or even memory limit is going to exceed? Does it require the knowledge of DSA?

generally we explicitly get TLE or Memory error but, here at hackerearth we are getting Runtime error NZEC. It does not require knowledge of DSA. It comes over the time with practice.

Okay, Thank you so much!
